# Drill down Map of Michigan-Counties-Cities

Tags: maps

am a website user and am trying to find an interactive map of the State of Michigan that drills down to counties and then to cities with option to put details/information on hover. Where can I get this? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Have been searching for days and have not been able to find a proper resource.